# Extend an existing struct in C# to add operators

Tags: c#, .net, struct, operator-keyword

I want to extend the .NET's built-in `Color` struct to add new operators like `+` or `-`.
I will use them like:

```
Color c1 = Color.FromName("Red");
Color c2 = Color.FromName("Blue");
Color result = c2 - c1;
```

Is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done but I am very curious as to what the result of 'red - blue' would be?

Comment: @n8wrl: Weird indeed, but I'd expect a `-` to remove whichever RGB values that color has from the other.

Comment: @n8wrl whatever the opposite of purple is, presumably :-)

Comment: it will do a component-wise subtraction for regular 24-bit colors, like subtract reds, greens, and blues. this is just a simple example to demonstrate, obviously the result will be Red in this example (as I'll be converting the negative values to 0), but I won't be using it to 'subtract red from blue' :)

Comment: ok, everyone, forget about `Color` to avoid further confusion. it's a C# question after all :) tell if extending an existing struct with an operator is possible or not..

Comment: Since extension methods **extend** the class/struct they can't be used to **replace** existing methods. They can, however, be used to create overloaded methods with different signatures.

Comment: @Yuck He's specifically talking about operator extensions. I know i've read something from Eric Lippert about them in the past as a possible future feature, but didn't have any plans right now. I don't have a link handy to where i read it though.

Comment: @asawyer: You are correct; we considered adding extension operators to C# 4.0 but wound up not having the time and budget for it. Perhaps in a hypothetical future version.

Comment: If the class is not sealed like your case, you can inherit from the class and define your own operator to that extended interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to do it with the built in operators.

You could write an extension method to kind of fake it though:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Color Substract(this Color color, Color theOtherColor)
    {
        //perform magic here! 
        //be sure to return something or this won't compile
    }
}

Color c1 = Color.FromName("Red");
Color c2 = Color.FromName("Blue");
Color result = c2.Subtract(c1);
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for defining an extension method on `Color`. Has to be a `static` class with `static` methods.

Comment: I Just noticed i was missing the `static` modifiers.

Comment: @asawyer, Remove `return null`. `Color` it's a value-type.

Comment: @Kirill Well it was only meant to express the idea, hence the comment about magic.

Answer (score 8):

As others suggested, you can go either the extension methods way or the Decorator pattern way.

However, consider that Color has a fair number of properties and methods, so redirecting them all from the decorator class to your wrapped Color struct will mean writing a lot of boilerplate. If you go that route, however, you can indeed define operators and even implicit conversions from your class to Color and the other way around (so that you can use them more interchangeably), like this:

```
public class MyColor {
    public System.Drawing.Color val;

    public MyColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        this.val = color;
    }

    public static MyColor AliceBlue 
    {
        get {
            return new MyColor(System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return val.ToString();
    }
    // .... and so on....

    // User-defined conversion from MyColor to Color
    public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Color(MyColor c)
    {
        return c.val;
    }
    //  User-defined conversion from Color to MyColor
    public static implicit operator MyColor(System.Drawing.Color c)
    {
        return new MyColor(c);
    }
}
```

to test:

```
MyColor c = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue; // assigning a Color to a MyColor
                                            // thanks to the implicit conversion
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()); // writes "Color [AliceBlue]"
```

Comment: this is a really nice example for a reference, but (in my current situation) it'd just make everything harder. nice code though, implicit operators really clean up the things while writing code.

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu I agree. I would personally use extensions in your scenario: my example was more meant to show you what a mess the other way would become with a "big" struct like Color....

Answer (score 3):

Structs and Classes in C# share a lot of similarities, however one of several difference is that you cannot subclass a struct.  You could use an extension method to implement an Add() or Subtract() method, but you cannot write an operator overload in an extension method.

If I were you and I really wanted to extend the functionality of an existing struct like this, I would wrap the struct in my own class.

Comment: +1 It does seem like a strange place to use extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`extension methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: i know about extension methods, but just wondering the possibility of using operators.

Comment: Than look at @iandotkelly answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that these already exist, are you talking about redefining them? These are operations on the alpha and RGB of the colors. See below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.op_subtraction.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.op_addition.aspx

Comment: The `Color` object the OP is asking about exists in the `System.Drawing` namespace. Not the one you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't extend something, you can also create a wrapper class or struct. In many cases a composition is actually more powerful and flexible than an extension.

It allows multiple inheritance, you can easily upgrade/wrap an existing object etc.

I'm not saying it is the best answer to this question, but certainly something worth considering. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since it came up on my DuckDuckGoSearch, I think it should be answered.

You **CAN** do this in C#. Now you can, anyway. Maybe not 9 years ago when this was asked.

See this documentation for all the info you need:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

Inside a struct, it looks like this:

```
public static Fraction operator -(Fraction a, Fraction b)
        => a + (-b);
```

Comment: You CAN'T though.
It was asked whether you can extend the **built-in** Color struct with a custom operator. 
The link you provided states:

*(...) An operator declaration must satisfy the following rules: (...) In each case, at least one parameter must have type T or T? where T is the type that contains the operator declaration.*

Since you can't put stuff into the definition of that built-in Color struct, you can't add a custom operator to it. 
The closest thing, as others have pointed out, is probably adding a extension method instead, which can't be an operator.